# Creating new Views by Drag and Drop & Controlling them (custom layouts)

Tags: android, android-layout, drag-and-drop

The main purpose of the app is to provide education courses for students.
I have two actors:

- Teachers who create the content of the course from inside the android app 
  where the lesson could be any combination of android views.
- Students who view these courses and interact with lessons, may be click button to hear sound (Only view this lessons)

**Stage 1 :** *Implementing drag and drop editor*
So far I have been able to create new Views (ImageViews TextViews ... etc) & drop them in new layout.

But once I drop them I have no control on them any longer. Now I am restricted to one style of layout, which I do not want. I want to reach the level of *android studio layout editor*, where I can add Views, change their position, size, etc.

**Stage 2 :** *Save layout* 
Would you suggest a way to save layout data to be shown to Students. JSON? XML?

**Stage 3:** *Parsing Layout data*
I have implemented XML parser and tested it using a layout that I had created in android studio. However, depending on your suggestion I may change the way I parse the lesson.

Drag & DropLayout Editor - Instructor Layout - Student Layout - Android Studio

[image: pic]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following:

- *Stage 1*

Create custom views for all widgets which can be dropped (`LinearLayout`, `ImageView`, etc). Let them all implement the following interface:

```
interface Layout {
  Layout getLayout();
  LayoutEditor getLayoutEditor();
}
```

Where `Layout` is the serializable representation of that view's layout (XML or JSON) and `LayoutEditor` is another interface which can used to modify the attributes on that `View` (layout_width, layout_height background, etc)

- *Stage 2*

So after you have dragged and dropped widgets on to say the app canvas you get a view hierarchy of Views which implement `Layout` interface. Just walk this tree recursively and call `getLayout()` on each view and stitch together a `Layout` hierarchy. Which you can then serialize and save.

- *Stage 3*

You deserialize the `Layout` you saved and walk through the layout tree and recreate the View hierarchy with it.

Check out [proteus](https://github.com/flipkart-incubator/proteus) for some inpiration. This uses JSON layouts to inflate native Android views.

Comment: Do you have any idea whether resizing or scaling a view would work using LayoutEditor or would it only work for drag and drop ?

Thanks in advance for this - going to test it

Comment: An easier to implement solution is when you long press or double tap a widget on the canvas take the user or open a form where you can edit the attributes values or add or delete them . Resizing scaling can be would be difficult to implement. The way you go about is by creating a touch listeners and gesture detector on all your custom widget. Personally I feel that would be an over kill for say version 1 of the app.

Comment: The layout editor is the interface you will use to build the form and interact with the form. It might have set(String attribute, Object value) and Object getAtrribute(String name) methods. Also Iterator getAllAttributes() to build your form page. Or something on those lines. I hope I was of help. All the best with your project.

Comment: If this was a satisfactory answer please mark it so for future generations :)